# Storing JSON array in MySQL Database Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, postman

I want to store an array of languages a user knows in the database.

My code:

```
 router.post('/create-user', async (req, res) =>{
      const query = `INSERT INTO users(name, languages, created_at, updated_at, deleted) 
                     VALUES ('${name}', ${languages}, NOW(), NOW(), 0)`;
      const result = await db.query(query);
      // rest of code..
    });
```

I defined a column `languages` in the database of type `JSON`.

I call this API in postman with `body`:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "languages" : "['English', 'German']"
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
 "error": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'English', 'German'].
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Jadenkun, which module are you using to interact with the db? ( mysql, mysql2, etc )
mysql2 support JSON data type https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/lib/constants/types.js#L22

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass multiple values at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly writing query - which is VERY BAD practice.
Instead use:

```
  const query = 'INSERT INTO users(name, languages, created_at, updated_at, deleted) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), ?)';
  const result = await db.query(query, [name, language, 0]);
```

Which will escape all problematic characters in the query, more you can read here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-prepared-statements

Comment: I'm actually getting an error using this approach - Error: Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'created_at' at row 1. My created_at column's type is TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Updated answer.....   NOW() shouldbt be escaped so it shouldnt be in parameters and inserterd by ?. Should work for you now

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to pass multiple values at once. Try:

```
 router.post('/create-user', async (req, res) =>{
      languages.forEach((language) => {

      const query = `INSERT INTO users(name, languages, created_at, updated_at, deleted) 
                     VALUES ('${name}', ${language}, NOW(), NOW(), 0)`;
      const result = await db.query(query);
      })

      // rest of code..
    });
```

Comment: Please - dont teach bad examples to new programmers. You should NEVER EVER write direct queries without sanitizing data before pushing them into the database.

Example here should look like (at least): 
`const query = 'INSERT INTO users(name, languages, created_at, updated_at, deleted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
      const result = await db.query(query, [name, language, 'NOW()', 'NOW()', 0]);
`